# Why the fill does not fully cover the traces and component in Kicad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

If the fill is touching the traces, it means they are same net, but why the fill does not engulf the trace and cover the component?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That via have clearance, the R7 north pad got clearance, instead you have thermal relief and one spoke out of 4 there.

[image: With zone surrounding the pad]

This is what it looks like in PCB new, when the zone is all around the pad (almost)

Comment: Via is far from R7, look at the R7 silk screen, there it touches, but down it does not.

Comment: Indeed far, but you pointed out with the top circle that the zone didn't touch the trace. That is because the via is there, with a clearance. Also the R7 got clearence not only the other pad but the one in the same net as the zone. See my picture, that the zone does not 'engulf' the pad.

Comment: What about this? https://i.imgur.com/fAkZsaG.png

Comment: Now you did move that via, you see now the trace disappear into the zone fill? That C3, I don't know what I'm looking at, sorry.

Comment: Both C3 and R7 are connected to the fill via a trace, but the fill should cover the components, but its keeping a distance from the component pad, which is on the same net.

Comment: And that's how it is supposed to be, it's the default settings in Kicad. Feel free to change those settings.

Comment: @Priyank - When defining a copper fill (zone) there can be different clearances set for the gap around a pad with thermal relief spokes vs other objects.  You could optionally change the thermal relief option to Solid.  Another factor is the Minimum width parameter, this may prevent a fill zone from squeezing down to flow between closely spaced pads or traces.

Comment: Turns out you need to set the Pad property: Connection to Zones as Solid and in the Zone property > electrical clearance, reduce it from 1mm to 0.5mm

Comment: By today's PCB standards 1mm (0.039") is a very large clearance space.